# Dificuldade com primeiro código

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esse é meu primeiro código que não envolve as aulas do meu curso. Meu objetivo é montar um código que peça que se insira um símbolo químico qualquer e este vai dizer seu grupo. Bem simple o conceito, mas estou tendo dificuldades nele.

```
elemento = str((input("Insira um elemento químico: ")))
if len(elemento) !=2: #Verifica se o elemento está em símbolo.
    input("Insira somente a sigla do elemento: ")

else:
    alcalinos = str(('Li', 'Na', 'K', 'Rb', 'Cs', 'Fr'))
    alcalinos_terrosos = str(('Be', 'Mg', 'Ca', 'Sr', 'Ba', 'Ra'))
    metais_de_transicao = str(('Sc', 'Y', 'Ti', 'Zr', 'Hf', 'Rf', 'V', 'Nb', 'Ta', 'Db', 'Cr', 'Mo', 'W', 'Sg', 'Mn', 'Tc', 'Re', 'Bh', 'Fe', 'Ru', 'Os', 'Hs', 'Co', 'Rh', 'Ir', 'Mt', 'Ni', 'Pd', 'Pt', 'Ds', 'Cu', 'Ag', 'Au', 'Rg', 'Zn', 'Cd', 'Hg', 'Cn'))

    if elemento == (alcalinos):
        print("Esse elemento é um Alcalino.")
    if elemento == (alcalinos_terrosos):
        print("Esse elemento é um Alcalino Terroso.")
    if elemento == (metais_de_transicao):
        print("Esse elemento é um metal de Transição.")
    elif elemento != ('Ac', 'Am', 'Sb', 'Ar', 'As', 'At', 'Ba', 'Bk', 
        'Be', 'Bi', 'Bh', 'B', 'Br', 'Cd', 'Cs', 'Ca', 'Cf', 'C', 'Ce', 
        'Cl', 'Cr', 'Co', 'Cu', 'Cm', 'Ds', 'Db', 'Dy', 'Es', 'Er', 'Eu', 'Fm',
        'F', 'Fr', 'Gd', 'Ga', 'Ge', 'Au', 'Hf', 'Hs', 'He', 'Ho', 'H', 'In',
        'I', 'Ir', 'Fe', 'Kr', 'La', 'Lr', 'Pb', 'Li', 'Lu', 'Mg', 'Mn',
        'Mt', 'Md', 'Hg', 'Mo', 'Nd', 'Ne', 'Np', 'Ni', 'Nb', 'N', 'No',
        'Os', 'O', 'Pd', 'P', 'Pt', 'Pu', 'Po', 'K', 'Pr', 'Pm', 'Pa', 'Ra',
        'Rn', 'Re', 'Rh', 'Rg', 'Rb', 'Ru', 'Rf', 'Sm', 'Sc', 'Sg', 'Se',
        'Si', 'Ag', 'Na', 'Sr', 'S', 'Ta', 'Tc', 'Te', 'Tb', 'Tl', 'Th', 
        'Tm', 'Sn', 'Ti', 'W', 'Uub', 'Uuh', 'Uuo', 'Uup', 'Uuq', 'Uus', 
        'Uut', 'U', 'V', 'Xe', 'Yb', 'Y', 'Zn', 'Zr'): 
            #Verifica se o símbolo é um elemento.Minha dificuldade é aqui.
        print("Elemento não existe.")
```

Comment: Inserindo elif ... not in resolveu, mas agora não recebo nenhum valor na saída. Vou trabalhar mais um pouco em cima dele.

Comment: @MarcelloFabrizio você teria que trocar todas as verificações por `in` e `not in` ... o `==` é só quando você quer testar por um valor específico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve testar usando o operador `in` para saber se um objeto faz parte de uma sequência.

Caso queira saber se o objeto não está na sequência, use `not in`.

Por exemplo:

```
if elemento in alcalinos:
    print("Esse elemento é um Alcalino.")
if elemento in alcalinos_terrosos:
    print("Esse elemento é um Alcalino Terroso.")
if elemento in metais_de_transicao:
    print("Esse elemento é um metal de Transição.")
elif elemento not in ('Ac', 'Am', 'Sb', 'Ar', ...):
```

Vai verificar se o `elemento` está ou não entre estes.

Comment: Agora consegui. Muitíssimo obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

```
elemento = str((input("Insira um elemento químico: ")))
alcalinos = ('Li', 'Na', 'K', 'Rb', 'Cs', 'Fr')
alcalinos_terrosos = ('Be', 'Mg', 'Ca', 'Sr', 'Ba', 'Ra')
metais_de_transicao = ('Sc', 'Y', 'Ti', 'Zr', 'Hf', 'Rf', 'V', 'Nb', 'Ta', 'Db', 'Cr', 'Mo', 'W', 'Sg', 'Mn', 'Tc', 'Re', 'Bh', 'Fe', 'Ru', 'Os', 'Hs', 'Co', 'Rh', 'Ir', 'Mt', 'Ni', 'Pd', 'Pt', 'Ds', 'Cu', 'Ag', 'Au', 'Rg', 'Zn', 'Cd', 'Hg', 'Cn')

if len(elemento) !=2:
        input("Insira somente a sigla do elemento: ")

elif elemento not in('Sc', 'Y', 'Ti', 'Zr', 'Hf', 'Rf', 'V', 'Nb', 'Ta', 'Db', 'Cr', 'Mo', 'W', 'Sg', 'Mn', 'Tc', 'Re', 'Bh', 'Fe', 'Ru', 'Os', 'Be', 'Mg', 'Ca', 'Sr', 'Ba', 'Ra', 'Li', 'Na', 'K', 'Rb', 'Cs', 'Fr'):
            print("Elemento não existe.")

else:
        if elemento in alcalinos:
                print("Esse elemento é um Alcalino.")
        if elemento in alcalinos_terrosos:
                print("Esse elemento é um Alcalino Terroso.")
        if elemento in metais_de_transicao:
                print("Esse elemento é um metal de Transição.")
```

Assim ele funciona do jeito que eu pensei nele.

Answer (score 0):

```
elementos = ('ac', 'am', 'sb', 'ar', 'as', 'at', 'ba', 'bk',
    'be', 'bi', 'bh', 'b', 'br', 'cd', 'cs', 'ca', 'cf', 'c', 'ce',
    'cl', 'cr', 'co', 'cu', 'cm', 'ds', 'db', 'dy', 'es', 'er', 'eu', 'fm',
    'f', 'fr', 'gd', 'ga', 'ge', 'au', 'hf', 'hs', 'he', 'ho', 'h', 'in',
    'i', 'ir', 'fe', 'kr', 'la', 'lr', 'pb', 'li', 'lu', 'mg', 'mn',
    'mt', 'md', 'hg', 'mo', 'nd', 'ne', 'np', 'ni', 'nb', 'n', 'no',
    'os', 'o', 'pd', 'p', 'pt', 'pu', 'po', 'k', 'pr', 'pm', 'pa', 'ra',
    'rn', 're', 'rh', 'rg', 'rb', 'ru', 'rf', 'sm', 'sc', 'sg', 'se',
    'si', 'ag', 'na', 'sr', 's', 'ta', 'tc', 'te', 'tb', 'tl', 'th',
    'tm', 'sn', 'ti', 'w', 'uub', 'uuh', 'uuo', 'uup', 'uuq', 'uus',
    'uut', 'u', 'v', 'xe', 'yb', 'y', 'zn', 'zr')

alcalinos = ('li', 'na', 'k', 'rb', 'cs', 'fr')
alcalinos_terrosos = ('be', 'mg', 'ca', 'sr', 'ba', 'ra')
metais_de_transicao = ('sc', 'y', 'ti', 'zr', 'hf', 'rf', 'v', 'nb', 'ta', 'db', 'cr', 'mo', 'w', 'sg', 'mn', 'tc',
                       're', 'bh', 'fe', 'ru', 'os', 'hs', 'co', 'rh', 'ir', 'mt', 'ni', 'pd', 'pt', 'ds', 'cu',
                       'ag', 'au', 'rg', 'zn', 'cd', 'hg', 'cn')

while True:
    elemento = str((input("Insira um elemento químico: ")))

    if len(elemento) !=2: #Verifica se o elemento está em símbolo.
       print("Insira somente a sigla do elemento!")
       continue
    else:
       break

if elemento.lower() in alcalinos:
    print("Esse elemento é um Alcalino.")
elif elemento.lower() in alcalinos_terrosos:
    print("Esse elemento é um Alcalino Terroso.")
elif elemento.lower() in metais_de_transicao:
    print("Esse elemento é um metal de Transição.")

elif elemento.lower() not in elementos:
    print("Elemento não existe!")
```